# macOS 10.13 Server app v5.6 PHP Downgrade From 7 to 5

Tags: php, macos, server, apache2, macos-high-sierra

Has anybody been able to successfully downgrade the php version preinstalled with the macOS High Sierra server app?

Preinstalled PHP version is 7 but I'm running some old PHP apps that require PHP version 5.

I can't find any recent answers on the topic.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not recommend downgrading the version, I would install PHP 5.6 using homebrew and then just having both versions installed.
`brew install php56`

This will be symlinked from `/usr/local/Cellar/php56` into `/usr/local/bin` and as long as this in in your `$PATH` then you should be able to use PHP 5.6 without overriding 7

Comment: this worked. All I had to do was change the apache config file to target the php56 installation instead of php7. Thanks

Comment: how did you do that?